# Java: Start sub process with own terminal

Tags: java, java-threads

I have two controllers and one program that starts them both.
One is an emulator that produces data, the other analyzes the data.
The two controllers depend on each other and communicate using RMI.
Therefore, I start the emulator in another thread and the analyzer in my main thread.
**That works perfectly fine.**

Now the problem is, that they both produce quite a lot of output on the console and I really would like them to print to two different terminals.
Is there a way to do that?

I tried to start the emulator as a sub process *within* a new command line (platform independence would be the next step)

```
String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
String path = System.getProperty("java.home")
            + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = 
            new ProcessBuilder(
            "\"" + path + "\"", 
            "-cp", 
            classpath,
            TheEumlator.class.getName());

String command = StringUtils.join(processBuilder.command(), " ");

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K %s", command));
```

However, the `classpath` is way too long and the output of `cmd.exe` is `The command line is too long.`

Do you have any idea how to produce another thread or process with its **own** output terminal?
I'd be happy for any suggestion.

Cheers

**UPDATE**

I combined the answer of OlaviMustanoja with this solution  http://unserializableone.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/redirecting-systemout-and-systemerr-to.html

It now uses standard `System.out`, `System.err` and stack trace. Also, it scrolls.

```
public class ConsoleWindow implements Runnable {

    private String title;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea outputArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public ConsoleWindow(String title, boolean redirectStreams) {
        this.title = title;
        this.outputArea = new JTextArea(30, 80);
        this.outputArea.setEditable(false);

        if (redirectStreams)
            redirectSystemStreams();
    }

    public ConsoleWindow(String title) {
        this(title, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame(this.title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        outputPanel.add(scrollPane);

        frame.add(outputPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void updateTextArea(final String text) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                outputArea.append(text);
            }
        });
    }

    private void redirectSystemStreams() {
        OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
                write(b, 0, b.length);
            }
        };

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
    }

    public void println(String msg) {
        updateTextArea(msg + "\n");
    }

    public void println(Throwable t) {
        println(t.toString());
    }

    public void print(String msg) {
        updateTextArea(msg);
    }

    public void printStackTrace(Throwable t) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        t.printStackTrace(pw);
        this.println(sw.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do they have to be terminals (linux) / command prompts (windows) / other OS-built-in consoles? I mean you could open two windows and append text to them. The other process outputs text to windowA and the other to windowB. This would also be platform independent.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Good question! I'm not entirely sure what the difference between terminals, command prompts and OS-built-in consoles is. Could you elaborate on that in a few words? Basically I need the programs output and (in case of an exception) stack trace (`System.out` and `System.err`).

Comment: There is no particular difference. Windows command prompt (cmd) serves the same purpose as the terminal in linux. What I meant was that is it neccessary to output the messages to these consoles? If not, you could simply implement a class (say, OutputWindow) that takes messages in some way and shows them in the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to output the messages to these consoles? If not, you could simply implement a class (say, OutputWindow) that takes messages in some way and shows them in the window.

To better illustrate the point I made in my comment, consider the following implementation of `OutputWindow`:

```
class OutputWindow implements Runnable {

    private String title;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea outputArea;

    public OutputWindow(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        this.outputArea = new JTextArea(15, 50);
        this.outputArea.setEditable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame(this.title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        outputPanel.add(outputArea);

        frame.add(outputPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void println(String msg) {
        outputArea.append(msg + "\n");
    }

    public void println(Throwable t) {
        this.println(t.toString());
    }

    public void print(String msg) {
        outputArea.append(msg);
    }

    public void printStackTrace(Throwable t) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        t.printStackTrace(pw);
        this.println(sw.toString());
    }

}
```

A simple, rather quickly tested piece of code. One would open a new "console" like this:

```
OutputWindow console = new OutputWindow("Console");
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(console);
```

You can try it out:

```
OutputWindow console = new OutputWindow("Console");
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(console);

try {
    System.out.println(2 / 0);     // just to throw an exception
} catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
    console.printStackTrace(ex);
}
```

The advantage in doing this is the extent to which you can customize it! Endless possibilities. Create your own state of the art console with super awesome colors and any kind of functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution here would be to write output to files, open your terminals manually and launch blocking tail

Comment: I thought about that as well. On my own machine I would have done this, but it is a shared project. So where to put the file? Then, the command for blocking tail is platform dependent... You get the point ;)